# Running Job.update_greeting without updating customized greetings

Tags: scheduled-job

When I run the Scheduled Job "Job.update_greeting" with those parameters

```
ct=Organization, Individual, Household
gt=email_greeting, postal_greeting, addressee
force=1
```

or also with less parameters and `force=1` then also customized greetings or addressees will be overwritten.
Is there any way to update all except the ones that are customized?

There is only the option force 0 but in [this docu](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/ca/latest/initial-set-up/scheduled-jobs/#job_update_greeting) I find this information:

> force 0 only contacts with null values are updated (default)

So this option is not very helpful since it does not do anything. We do not have any contacts with null values in this field. In my opinion we are missing another option here (only update defaults but leave customized values as they are).

Any thoughts on this?